# Printing two digits after decimal in go

Tags: go, decimal

I want to print two digits after decimal after rounding in GO language..
e.g 1.222225 should be printed as 1.22
1.356 should be printed as 1.36

How can i do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can write:

```
fmt.Printf("%.2f", 1.22225)
```

(See http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/.)

Comment: thanks..it worked.i was using fmt.Println()..so i was not getting correct answer

Answer (score 8):

If you use the `fmt.Printf` function there is syntax in the formatting string that lets you print floats to a given level of precision like this. The general syntax is `%.[numberofdigits]f`.

Examples:

`fmt.Printf("%.2f" 1.2222225) // output: 1.22`

`fmt.Printf("%.2f", 1.356) // output: 1.36`

One thing to note is that the round doesn't "carry"

`fmt.Printf("%.1f", 1.346)`

Will output 1.3, not 1.4. Additionally, negative numbers will behave as expected:

`fmt.Printf("%.2f", -1.356) // output: -1.36`

Comment: thanks..sorry i do not have 15 reputation..so i am not able to upvote ur answer..anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a `Decimal64p2` type of decimal with fixed .00 precision - https://github.com/strongo/decimal

Comparing to `fmt.Printf("%.1f", 1.346)` it will round correctly.

It is efficient for storing exact amounts of money.